# Camuda 7.7.0 - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint “act_hi_varinst_pkey”

Tags: postgresql, camunda

With Camunda 7.7.0 (and CamundaSpringBoot 2.2.0) sometimes the following error occurs:

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-03004 Exception while executing Database Operation ‘INSERT HistoricVariableInstanceEntity[244ed9a2-8f6b-11e8-9240-0242c0a83005]’ with message ’

Error updating database. Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint “act_hi_varinst_pkey”
Detail: Key (id_)=(244ed9a2-8f6b-11e8-9240-0242c0a83005) already exists.
```

I configured the engine to use the StrongUUIDGenerator as documented [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/process-engine/id-generator/) but the problem was not fixed.  Any ideas?